# Passport.authenticate successRedirect condition after Google OAuth 2.0 identification

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I use this Callback route after Google OAuth 2.0 identification

```
// Original version working:
// Callback route
router.get( '/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        failureRedirect: '/', 
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
}));
```

I want to redirect the general users to '/dashboard/ but the admin (With email like admin@admin.com ) to '/admin'

I'm trying something like this:

```
// Callback route
router.get( '/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        failureRedirect: '/', 
          {
            if (req.user.mail === 'admin@admin.com') {
                return successRedirect: '/admin';
            } else 
                {
                return successRedirect: '/dashboard';
            }
    }
}));
```

**But I don´t know how to insert the (req, res) after the failureRedirect: '/',  line**

**Also the "return" is needed?**

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a custom callback as prescribed by the package [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/#custom-callback).

**Implementation**:

```
router.get('/google/callback', (req, res, next) =>
  passport.authenticate('google', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    if  (!user) return res.redirect('/login');

    req.logIn(user, err => {
      if (err) return next(err);

      if (user.mail === 'admin@admin.com') return res.redirect('/admin');

      return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
  })(req, res, next)
);
```

Comment: Thanks,solved my question. New info for me, just learning at this time.